# React Native debugger with device on VPN

Tags: react-native, vpn, react-native-debugger

My application on Android relies on VPN connection, hence I can't enter "React Native Debug" after connecting device with VPN.

**Things I have tried: (but failed)**

1. Without VPN established, I can always `debug` or `reload` my application
2. Tried vice versa way of entering `debug` mode first then establish VPN. Once VPN is established, the connection between app and laptop is disconnected.

Any idea or direction I can look into?

Comment: Add some rules to your VPN to skip the LAN address

Comment: You mean, whitelisting my localhost's IP within VPN? In my working environment, the IP address is assigned dynamically. Hence whitelisting, do not work for me.